# Exception with using Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, exception

Please help me.

Crushed in insert on table data, column `setCreateDate`. Who knows what this error is and why there is no possibility to write a timestamp `DateTime` object????

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "2015-02-24 13:48:32.575000 +02:00:00"
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2102)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1835)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:257)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:500)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:388)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeUpdate(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:334)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:56)
    ... 56 more
```

Class Dao:

```
import com.tatem.persistance.dao.core.GenericDao;
import com.tatem.persistance.domain.core.DomainObject;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
public class GenericDaoHibernate<T extends DomainObject> implements GenericDao<T> {

private Class<T> type;
@Autowired
private HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate;

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public GenericDaoHibernate(Class<T> type) {
    this.type = type;
}


@Override
public T get(Serializable id) {
    return hibernateTemplate.get(type, id);
}

@Override
public List<T> getAll() {
    return hibernateTemplate.loadAll(type);
}

@Override
public Serializable save(T object) {
    Serializable id = (Serializable) hibernateTemplate.save(object);
    hibernateTemplate.flush();
    return id;
}

@Override
public void saveBulk(List<T> objects){
    hibernateTemplate.saveOrUpdateAll(objects);
    hibernateTemplate.flush();
}

public HibernateTemplate getHibernateTemplate() {
    return hibernateTemplate;
}

@Override
public void merge(T object) {
    hibernateTemplate.merge(object);
    hibernateTemplate.flush();
}

@Override
public void update(T object){
    hibernateTemplate.update(object);
    hibernateTemplate.flush();
}

@Override
public void delete(T object) {
    hibernateTemplate.delete(object);
    hibernateTemplate.flush();
}

@Override
public void deleteAll(List<T> objects) {
    hibernateTemplate.deleteAll(objects);
    hibernateTemplate.flush();
}

@Override
public void bulkSaveOrUpdate(List<T> objects) {
    hibernateTemplate.saveOrUpdateAll(objects);
    hibernateTemplate.flush();
}
}
```

Class Hibernate:

```
import com.tatem.bookingserver.rest.json.model.notification.InternalNotificationType;

import com.tatem.persistance.domain.core.DomainObject;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;

import org.joda.time.DateTime;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "internal_notification")
public class InternalNotificationEntity implements DomainObject {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;

@Column(name = "user_id")
private long userId;

@Column(name = "created_ts")
@Type(type = "org.joda.time.contrib.hibernate.PersistentDateTime")
private DateTime createDate;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private InternalNotificationType type;

@Column
private String message;

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public DateTime getCreateDate() {
    return createDate;
}

public void setCreateDate(DateTime createDate) {
    this.createDate = createDate;
}

public InternalNotificationType getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(InternalNotificationType type) {
    this.type = type;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}

public long getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public void setUserId(long userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}

}
```

Comment: Looks like you are trying to save date into int column.

Comment: Check your DB table, it seems the column you are trying to save in the timestamp is not of the right type.

Comment: Don't know postgress, but is there a difference between timestamps with a timezone and timestamps withouth?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing `@Temporal` annotation on `createDate` mapping. It should be something like this

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP) 
private Date createDate;
```

This mapping expects a database column of type `timestamp` (based on your needs, it can be `date` or any similar type).

Comment: Thank you for response, but this use if Date from java.util.Date, code which I consider using DateTime from the library org.joda.time.DateTime.

Comment: Yes, Joda's `DateTime` can be used, with `@Type(type = "org.joda.time.contrib.hibernate.PersistentDateTime")`, but I see in your edited post you already figured that out.

Answer (score 0):

Thank all, as written @StanislavL turned mismatch types, table column `created_ts bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT fn_now_as_bigint()`